# Telegram API how to get a user First Name and Last name by telegram username

Tags: java, telegram

I need to get information about a user from @username. I'm not using telegram bot. I have a list of usernames, and I need to get information about users(First name and Last name).

How can I implement this in java? Is it possible? Maybe some website can give information about user from username?

Comment: You can't do this with Bot API, so Java is not possible

Comment: @Sean, is that possible using any other methods? (without help of Java)

Comment: You have to use client API

Comment: @Sean, can you please provide some code in any language? Code that will print Full name of user by username? If you can, please answer to my question and i mark as correct)

Comment: If you want I can write code to Python for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a try to [`tdlib/td`](https://github.com/tdlib/td), a cross-platform library for building Telegram clients created by Telegram in C++. You can use it in Java via JNI (Java Native Interface). They provide a [Java client example](https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example/java) to help you get started and build your own client. If you successfully followed the Java README and **build the JNI library yourself**, you'll find a generated file call `TdApi.java` in the Java folder.

From the generated `TdApi.java`, you can use static inner class `TdApi#GetUse(int userId)` to query a target user:

```
client.send(new TdApi.GetUser(userId), result -> {
  if (result.getConstructor() != User.CONSTRUCTOR) {
    System.out.println("Error occurred: " + result);
    return;
  }
  User user = (User) result;
  System.out.println(user.firstName);
  System.out.println(user.lastName);
  System.out.println(user.username);
});
```

Note that:

- The `TdApi.java` is generated, you don't find it in the codebase.
- The constructor of `TdApi.GetUser` does not accept username as input. You need to provide the user ID. User IDs can be found from the chat list.

Related resources:

- [Telegram Database Library](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib)
- [TDLib Java example](https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example/java)
- [td_api.tl `getUser user_id:int32 = User;`](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/td/generate/scheme/td_api.tl#L2054-L2055)
- [td_api.tl `user`](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/td/generate/scheme/td_api.tl#L276-L281)